# Importing contact form in front-page.php

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

Hello guys I'm trying to make custom contact form and I'm having some problems.
I made `page-contact-us.php` in my theme files and made Contact Us page in CMS.
This is the code:

```
<?php
//response generation function

$response = "";

//function to generate response
function my_contact_form_generate_response($type, $message) {

    global $response;

    if ($type == "success")
        $response = "<div class='success'>{$message}</div>";
    else
        $response = "<div class='error'>{$message}</div>";
}

//response messages
$not_human = "Human verification incorrect.";
$missing_content = "Please supply all information.";
$email_invalid = "Email Address Invalid.";
$message_unsent = "Message was not sent. Try Again.";
$message_sent = "Thanks! Your message has been sent.";

//user posted variables
$name = $_POST['message_name'];
$email = $_POST['message_email'];
$message = $_POST['message_text'];
$human = $_POST['message_human'];

//php mailer variables
$to = get_option('admin_email');
$subject = "Someone sent a message from " . get_bloginfo('name');
$headers = 'From: ' . $email . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n";

if (!$human == 0) {
    if ($human != 2)
        my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $not_human); //not human!
    else {

        //validate email
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
            my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $email_invalid);
        else { //email is valid
            //validate presence of name and message
            if (empty($name) || empty($message)) {
                my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $missing_content);
            } else { //ready to go!
                $sent = wp_mail($to, $subject, strip_tags($message), $headers);
                if ($sent)
                    my_contact_form_generate_response("success", $message_sent); //message sent!
                else
                    my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $message_unsent); //message wasn't sent
            }
        }
    }
}
else if ($_POST['submitted'])
    my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $missing_content);
?>



<div id="respond">
    <?php echo $response; ?>
    <form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" method="post">
        <div class="inputs-style">
            <input type="text" id="name" name="message_name" required value="<?php echo esc_attr($_POST['message_name']); ?>">
            <span class="floating-label">YOUR NAME</span>
        </div>

        <div class="inputs-style">
            <input type="text" id="email" name="message_email" required value="<?php echo esc_attr($_POST['message_email']); ?>">
            <span class="floating-label">YOUR E-MAIL</span>
        </div>

        <div class="inputs-style">
            <textarea class="autoExpand" type="text" data-min-rows='' rows="1" required name="message_text"><?php echo esc_textarea($_POST['message_text']); ?></textarea>
            <span class="floating-label">YOUR MESSAGE</span>
        </div>

      <!-- <p>
        <label for="name">Name: <span>*</span> <br>
          <input type="text" name="message_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr($_POST['message_name']); ?>">
        </label>
      </p>

      <p>
        <label for="message_email">Email: <span>*</span> <br>
          <input type="text" name="message_email" value="<?php echo esc_attr($_POST['message_email']); ?>">
        </label>
      </p>

      <p>
        <label for="message_text">Message: <span>*</span> <br>
          <textarea type="text" name="message_text">
        <?php echo esc_textarea($_POST['message_text']); ?>
          </textarea>
        </label>
      </p> -->

        <p>
            <label for="message_human">Human Verification: <span>*</span> <br>
                <input type="text" style="width: 60px;" name="message_human"> + 3 = 5
            </label>
        </p>
        <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1">

        <input class="btn btn-imperium btn-2" type="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

Now when I use it directly as page It works well, but when I try to import to my `front-page.php` like this `<?php include('page-contact-us.php'); ?>`  it doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to make it work in my `front-page.php` ?

Comment: Explain “it doesn’t work”, what error does it give you?

Comment: @NoImaginationGuy Sorry for not giving more details, but the thing is I get no error. Form works when I use it Contact Us page but when import in front-page.php it does not, but it does redirect me to one of my posts in my custom post type. It makes no sense to be honest.

Comment: code formatted and page name highlighted

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you provided the right address of the template. It should be like this,

```
<?php include(get_template_directory_uri().'/page-contact-us.php'); ?>
```

In order to make sure it includes you might want to change include() function to require().

Comment: The address is good. HTML part can be clearly seen on page. When I tried to include with the code above I get this `Warning: include(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0 in C:\wamp\www\imperum\wp-content\themes\imperum\front-page.php on line 331` and this `Warning: include(http://localhost/imperum/wp-content/themes/imperum/page-contact-us.php): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in C:\wamp\www\imperum\wp-content\themes\imperum\front-page.php on line 331`

Comment: You need to go to your php.ini file in WAMP and turn `allow_url_include=0` to `allow_url_include=1`

Comment: I can try that but I already tried your code directly on server with no luck. When I use your code on server nothing happens. Nothing gets imported.

Comment: Like I mentioned, change include() to require(). It forces code to include else stops program execution.

Comment: I have tried require.When I use it here http://imperium-la.com/contact-us/  it works but not in front-page.php when I import it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the get_template_part() function? It's the way code parts are meant to be imported into theme files. 
You can read more about it [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/).

Comment: Same thing happens as with regular import. It imports the code, but it doesn't work. It redirects me to one of my posts in my custom post type. It makes no sense to be honest.

Comment: Have you flushed the permalinks after creating the custom post type templates?